# Having problems with laravel blade templating and special characters

Tags: php, apache, laravel, frameworks, special-characters

im using the framework laravel 5.1 for a web page im currently working, im trying to use the special characters for spanish lenguage, but it doesnt seem to recognize them.

i've tried a simple code just to prove

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>ñ</p>
<p>&aacute;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

the locale config in app.php are set to "es" and I used all the metas for lang es and "utf-8", yet it doesn't seem to work

im using xampp for my localhost server and as a hosting im using neubox, in both of them the special characters render as this : "�"

Comment: Is your template file saved in utf8 format?

Comment: yeah, it is, and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save your document with encoding set to UTF-8 without BOM.

To do this with Sublime Text for example you hit "File"->"Save with encoding"->"UTF-8 with BOM"